# Reason for defining a quantity with "inf"

Tags: statistics, notation

In some applications (in my case statistics) I find quantities defined using "inf", e.g.

$ ABC = \inf\{x|F_X(x)\ge\alpha\}$

Why not define simply:

$F_X(x=ABC) = \alpha$

I imagine it has something to do with the possibility of multiple values for $x$ satisfying the condidion, right?

Assuming, single valued solutions to the condition could be garanteed, is there a prettier notation for defining ABC without using set builder notation? (Since there is only a single value, set notation seems non-intuitive.)

$ ABC = \{x|F_X(x)=\alpha\}$

Comment: multiple or none. The point is that $\inf A$ **exists** as soon as $A$ is non-empty and bounded from below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why one writes "inf" in this case is that there may not be any x satisfiying $F_X(x) = \alpha$. In this case the "equals" condition would yield an empty set and be useless. Therefore you need to define it as the infimum.

Consider for example $\alpha=0$, $x \in M = \{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $F(x)=x$. Then there exists no $x$ such that $F(x) = \alpha$, but $\inf_{x \in M} \{x | F(x)\geq \alpha \} = \{0\}$.

If it can be shown that $\exists ! x \text{ }$ such that $F_X(x)=\alpha $, then you can simply define $x =F^{-1}_X(\alpha) $.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Just one clarification: what does the ! after the "there exists" symbol mean?

Comment: Hey Marvin, the ! after the "there is" symbol means "there is a unique". For instance, $\exists ! x\in \mathbb{R}: x=1$ is a true statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation really doesn't make sense. Perhaps you can clarify it?

Note that the quantity $\{x:F_X(x)\geq \alpha\}$ is frequently written as $$F_X^{-1}([\alpha,\infty))$$ so the quantity in question is just $$\inf F_X^{-1}([\alpha,\infty))$$
The infimum is used because the set may not contain its lower bound (if it *does* contain this lower bound, then the infimum is simply the minimum). Except for that, you are essentially finding the "smallest" value of $x$ such that $F_X(x)\geq\alpha$. If there is a "hole" in the graph of $F_X$ at height $\alpha$, this would be the greatest value of $x$ that isn't mapped above the hole.